# Don't understand error reading improper permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, pyautogui

I'm trying to make a bot for a game using pyautogui, however when this line of code runs:

```
    if py.locateOnScreen(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\Poison.png")!=None:
```

It returns this error:

```
OSError: Failed to read C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\Poison.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
```

Reading this error I checked that the pictures where both the right file type and that the file path was correct, on top of that I also checked that png is a supported file type for the pyautogui library. Therefore the only problem I can see is that it has improper permissions. My question is therefore if it is so and how I correct it then or how I could check this myself

all pointers appreciated!

*If it helps, here's my full code and after that full error*

```
import pyautogui as py
import winsound
from time import sleep as sl
Hello=[]
turn=0
while True:
    if py.locateOnScreen(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\Poison.png")!=None:
        if turn==0:
            pyautogui.typewrite(["a","f","s"], interval=0.4)

        elif turn==1:
            pyautogui.typewrite(["a","e"], interval=0.4)
        elif turn==2:
            pyautogui.typewrite(["a","a","s"], interval=0.4)
        elif turn==3:
            pyautogui.typewrite(["d"], interval=0.4)
        sl(1)
        turn+=1
        if turn==5:
            pyautogui.typewrite(["a","d"], interval=0.4)
            turn=0
    elif py.locateOnScreen(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\sidekick1.png")!=None:
            pyautogui.typewrite(["d"], interval=0.4)
            sl(1)
    elif py.locateOnScreen(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\sidekick2.png")!=None:
            pyautogui.typewrite(["d"], interval=0.4)
            sl(1)
    else:
            sl(1)

    Hello = py.locateAllOnScreen(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\HP.png")
    if len(Hello)==2:
        break
    Hello=[]
    if py.locateOnScreen(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\onwards.png")!=None:
        x,y=py.locateOnScreen(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\onwards.png")
        py.click(x, y)
        sleep(1)
    elif py.locateOnScreen(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\Check.png")!=None:
        winsound.Beep(1000, 100)  # Beep at 1000 Hz for 100 ms
        py.alert(text="Clear the captcha",title="__Alert__", button="Done")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/molta/Documents/Pythons/coliseum bot'.py", line 7, in <module>
    if py.locateOnScreen(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\Poison.png")!=None:
  File "C:\Users\molta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 300, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\molta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 281, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\molta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 146, in _locateAll_opencv
    needleImage = _load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale)
  File "C:\Users\molta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 113, in _load_cv2
    "unsupported or invalid format" % img)
OSError: Failed to read C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\Poison.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
```

Comment: it can means that file doesn't exists (or path is incorrect), or it is broken or it is in other user folder which you can't access. First you could check `print(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\"))` to see if file is in this folder.

Comment: The only likely reason for a permission problem here is that your script is running as some user other than `molta`.  You could try accessing the file a bit more directly - `open(r"C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\Poison.png").read()` perhaps.  This might give a more detailed error.

Comment: @jasonharper The code you gave me raises the filenotfounderror however when I entered the code from furas/the comment above yours it shows that the files I'm looking for are in this folder.

Comment: Then the filename must not be exactly what it looks like - a leading or trailing space perhaps, or a non-ASCII character.  Please add the output from that `listdir()` to your question.

Comment: Your code is difficult to read, please follow naming conventions and use a more appropriate amount of whitespace. Also, you should test if a variable is `None` using `is None` or `is not None`, not `==`.

Comment: @jasonharper you were right about there being a leading or trailing space, or a non-ASCII character in the name. Therefore my script now works when I've renamed my file. Because of you being the person who helped me solve it I would appreciate if you could format an answer instead of a comment, so that I can mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same problem mate and I found a solution that worked for me.
What I did was:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r"path") 
y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently got the same problem but I managed to find a way to solve it.
The folder where my .py and photos were located had improper permissions.
I deleted that folder(it was located in the C: drive) and I made a new one on my desktop and everything worked fine!