# Whatsapp Bot Problem when identifying any onLocateScreen object with Python

Tags: python, bots, whatsapp

```py
import pyautogui as pt
from time import sleep
import pyperclip
import random

sleep(3)

position1 = pt.locateOnScreen("whatsapp/smile.png", confidence=.6)
x = position1[0]
y = position1[1]

# Gets Message
def get_message():
    global x, y

    position = pt.locateOnScreen("whatsapp/smile.png", confidence=.6)
    x = position[0]
    y = position[1]
    pt.moveTo(x, y, duration=.05)

get_message()
```

When I try to run this code and open Whatsapp desktop, it fails and shows an error message like

> OSError: Failed to read whatsapp/smile.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

The title and the image format are correct. I've checked it many times. Any other suggestions on what might be the issue here?

Comment: Try read [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604926/dont-understand-error-reading-improper-permissions). I think you need something like `img = cv2.imread(r"<path-here>")` and then pass it to `position = pt.locateOnScreen(img, confidence=.6)`.

Comment: Really appreciate it. Thank you. Now my program can run without any problems

Comment: No problem, glad to help!