# Failed to read instance.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have this following code to wait for an icon to appear before clicking on it:

```
import pyautogui as py
from pyautogui import *

# Open BlueStacks from taskbar:
py.moveTo(2094, 1059, 1.2)
py.click()

# Wait for maximise icon to appear: 
status = False

while (status == False):
    if(py.locateOnScreen('maximise.png') is not None):
        py.click(py.center(py.locateOnScreen('maximise.png')))
        status = True
```

However when I run the script I get this:

```
[alex@silo Projects]$ /sbin/python /home/alex/Documents/Projects/foodOrderer/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/Documents/Projects/foodOrderer/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    max = py.locateOnScreen('maximise.png')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 372, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 352, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 206, in _locateAll_opencv
    needleImage = _load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 169, in _load_cv2
    raise IOError("Failed to read %s because file is missing, "
OSError: Failed to read maximise.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
```

I have previously had issues with this improper format error and have never found a solution online.
I am using Arch Linux and Visual Studio Code.

This is what I have tried already:

- [Don't understand error reading improper permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604926/dont-understand-error-reading-improper-permissions) - the only reply to this post. I get another TypeError: expected image filname...
- chmod a+rwx /home/alex/Documents/Projects (this is where the file is located)

Comment: This error is normally due to typos in the path name. Check if you typed them out correctly and if they're in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, and solved it by using the absolute path of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem. In my case the picture was in a folder synchronized by OneDrive. After moving it to a folder not touched by OneDrive, my code worked.
Before, I tried only closing OneDrive, but it was not enough.